# Why does the designated role still see masked data?

Tags: data-masking

I am trying to implement dynamic masking on a text field.
I created a new custom user, test1, (see picture below) and granted it a role called view_pi (see picture below).
I also created the following masking policy and applied it to the hobby column.

I don't understand why user text1 in view_pi role still has the hobby column masked -> see 3rd picture below.

Would appreciate any help.

Thank you

Yoram

Making policy:

create or replace masking policy text_field_mask as (val string) returns string ->

case

```
when current_role() in ('view_pi') then val

else '**Masked**'
```

end;

alter table if exists family modify column hobby set masking policy text_field_mask;

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved with the help of Marina from the support center in Amsterdam.
Role name comparison is case sensitive.
Roles are stored in the DB in upper case and my masking policy used lower case letter for the role.

"view_pi" does not equal "VIEW_PI".

Have fun!